# What is the geometrical interpretation of $\alpha\cos(\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the unit circle, what is the geometrical interpretation of this quantity $$\alpha\cos(\alpha)$$

such that $\alpha\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: Well, $(\alpha\cos(\alpha),\,\alpha\sin(\alpha))$ is a *spiral* (letting $\alpha>0$).

Comment: Why should the product of an angle and its cosine have a geometrical interpretation?

Comment: That, too, in a unit circle.